# VoltDB Cluster PAUSED when 2 node reaches to 80% memory out of 9 nodes

Tags: voltdb

I am importing data from Kafka server using VoltDB Kafka Importer, my current setup is in **AWS** and all the 9 nodes has following config

> **8 vCPUs**
>
> **200 GB HDD**
>
> **8 GB RAM**

The import rate is **10,000** recs per second.

My problem is the cluster enters into in Read-only mode after importing **42 million records**, even if other 7 nodes are using only **20-30%** of memory.

My table and stored procedure are partitioned. I enabled auto snapshot as well with 1 Hr frequency.

I am expecting **144** million records

What changes I should do to my configuration and how I can move data from memory to disk.

Please help.

Comment: It sounds like one or perhaps two servers are reaching 80% RAM, while others are using much less. What is the partitioning key for your main tables? It sounds like perhaps you have partitioned on a column that does not have high cardinality, so most of the workload is going to one partition.

Comment: Here is my table and partition details                                                                              

create table tsensor(
sensor_id integer not null,
clockTime timestamp,
airTemp varchar(30),
windSpeed varchar(30),
surfaceTemp varchar(30),
latitude varchar(30),
longitude varchar(30),
receive_time timestamp default now()
);

PARTITION TABLE TSENSOR ON COLUMN SENSOR_ID;

the procedure which inserts data is also partitioned on the same key, there are 100 possible sensor_ids

Comment: What is the range of values of sensor_id? With only 100 values, there could be a data skew. What are your sitesperhost and kfactor settings? The web interface Analysis tab, Data sub-tab can show the distribution of the tsensor table across your partitions. It may be very uneven.

Comment: Sensor is range is 0 - 99. Host per node is 8 and kfactor is 1.

Comment: You could try a lower sitesperhost, that might give a more even distribution. Do the sensors emit data evenly?

Comment: Very surprising..isnt this something VoltDB is supposed to handle itself. If there are 100 possible ids and only 9 nodes why doesn't it get distributed evenly?

Comment: After reducing site per host and fixing the code the scalability improved. The was randomly generating the ids which somehow attributed to the issue. Assigning is in round robin fashion helped.